# Spring and MongoDB Async Java Driver - clusterListener can not be null

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to connect to MongoDB using MongoDB's async Java driver.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
```

However, it is throwing following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: clusterListener can not be null
    at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.notNull(Assertions.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterSettings$Builder.addClusterListener(ClusterSettings.java:218)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.getClusterSettings(DefaultClusterFactory.java:190)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:46)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.createCluster(MongoClients.java:96)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:55)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients.create(MongoClients.java:45)
    at com.monbodb.async.mongoasync.MongoasyncApplication.main(MongoasyncApplication.java:22)
```

Has anyone encountered this before and has a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just update to mongo driver version (Latest) and rebuild the project with latest dependencies.

I have solved this issue with a rebuild.